# "I don't believe there can be such a thing" or "I don't believe such a thing exists", which one is more appropriate?

Tags: meaning

This [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/225966/95385) says

> I don't believe there can be such a thing as "non-sequential" ordering, because if any items were listed without a sequence then they would not be any order.

The expression "there can be" sounds uncommon, is this expression "I don't believe non-sequential ordering exists" more idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are fine, and they are basically equivalent. There's no problem with "there can be," in my opinion.

There may be a very slight difference in meaning. The simple version "I don't believe X exists" seems to accept that X may be well-defined but probably doesn't exist. The "I don't believe such a thing as 'X' exists" means that although someone can say "X," it doesn't have a well-defined meaning, so it doesn't even make sense to talk about whether or not it exists.